# How to change the title of breadcrumb?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I have a route that renders a node. Unfortunately in the breadcrumb the route title is rendered rather than the node title. When I preprocess in hook_preprocess_breadcrumb() inside my module only the preceding links are available inside $variable (*not* the current route title).

However, if I go to do hook_preprocess_breadcrumb() in my theme, the route title *is* inside $variables. So I could change it there but I want the functionality to be encapsulated inside my module, not split between module and theme.

I tried to create my own custom breadcrumb builder but I don't want to build it from scratch as there is some complex functionality built by other developers. I want to get the current breadcrumbs and then just replace the last one (the current page title) with my own.

I tried hook_system_breadcrumb_alter() as well but again the current page title is not showing up in variables inside my module.

```
<?php

class DefaultProductListBreadcrumbService implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {

  /**
   * Whether this breadcrumb builder should be used to build the breadcrumb.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The current route match.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if this builder should be used or FALSE to let other builders
   *   decide.
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // TODO: Implement applies() method.
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Builds the breadcrumb.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface $route_match
   *   The current route match.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb
   *   A breadcrumb.
   */
  public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // TODO: Implement build() method.

    $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
    $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));

    return $breadcrumb;
  }

}
```

For reference, I'm using bootstrap as the base theme with multiple sub themes (it's a multisite). I can't find anywhere that's adding the page title in the theme. I'm also using easy_breadcrumb module but I checked there and the page title is also not shown there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a title callback, like for example this one from the core node controller:

*\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController::title*

```
  public function title(EntityInterface $node) {
    return $this->entityManager->getTranslationFromContext($node)->label();
  }
```

Your title callback would have other route parameters, so that you can find the correct node, see also https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/248687/47547.

When using the default option in the Bootstrap theme to display the page title you might need to add cache metadata to the breadcrumb, see [Breadcrumbs are cached](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222615/breadcrumbs-are-cached/), which depends on how you determine the node to display.

Comment: This does change the title of the breadcrumb but for example, what if I want the <title> tag and page title to be one thing e.g. 'New York Accomodation' but the breadcrumb to be just 'accomodation'. I still have the same problem in that the hooks do not show the title in the module, only on the theme layer.

Comment: This should work with the current title handling in Drupal, set 'accomodation' in `_title_callback` and 'New York Accomodation' in `#title`of the main content (this is `$build['#title']` in the controller).

Comment: Unfortunately the <title> tag will be the same as the breadcrumb if I do that.

Comment: No, for the <title> tag, `#title` in the main content takes precedence over the route title. Check for other code trying to set the title, for example Metatag.